# How to get a li element using angular.element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and i'm trying to get a li from ul using angular.element and add a class to it.
But it doesn't seem to work and it shows 'undefined'. Where am I going wrong ?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [
      'John',
      'Doe'
  ];

  console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('container'))[0].children[1]);    
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/gfyDlLeXcbc0uAIxPE93?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because when you call the `console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('container'))[0].children[1]);`, the rendering phase is not started yet and no `<li>` is rendered at this time.

If you need to add a class **dynamically**, I recommend using [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6P61FIgwNfBo7krIYPz7?p=preview) how to use `ng-class`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LQsm7rLEikovpp4Kjc88?p=preview) how to use `class` with `{{}}`

Comment: @user1184100: if you add static class, using normal `class` html attribute should be enough. For dynamical classes based on model state, you should use `ng-class` as it plays well with angular cycle. Another way is using `{{}}` with `class`. Something like `class="{{myclass}}"`.

Comment: @user1184100: check my demos.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to pass $index in ng-class like this.. <li ng-class="{someClass : isActive($index)}" ></li>. In isActive function i get index undefined. Is it because the li is not rendered ?

Comment: @user1184100: $index is the index of current item, it's not undefined . http://plnkr.co/edit/ejEE7nKvctmoPqgt9kmx?p=preview. Inside your `isActive`, you have to return a true or false value to indicate to ng-class that this class should be added.

Comment: @user1184100: in my demo, $even and $odd are boolean, that's why it works.